# disable modal to close, after clicked a button

Tags: bootstrap-modal

[image]

I want to make this Modal like this:

1. in first popup, you can close this modal by click cancel button or close mark button or click the outside of modal.
2. when you click yes button, you cannot close the modal by click cancel button or close mark button or click the outside of modal, until the ajax process done.

how to achieve this?
I have try using javascript when you click yes button, I change data-backdrop to static and data-keyboard to false. But didnt work.

Comment: Please include a [mre] to your question. Otherwise it's hard to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using loading animation that blocked over your page.

you can define 2 function such as loading() and stoploading().

here's an example :

**CSS**

```
    #overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }

    .cv-spinner {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .spinner {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 4px #ddd solid;
        border-top: 4px #2e93e6 solid;
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: sp-anime 0.8s infinite linear;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay">
        <div class="cv-spinner">
            <span class="spinner"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--your content goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Function Using jQuery**

```
    function loading() {
        $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);
    }

    function stoploading() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
        }, 500);
    }
```

Ajax usage Example

```
function something(){
        loading();
        $.ajax({
            type: "method",
            url: "url",
            data: "data",
            dataType: "dataType",
            success: function (response) {
                //your function code goes here
                stoploading();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ahh, instead of confusing to disable specific buttons, the idea is to make an overlay layer that you cannot close it until Ajax did. thanks, I'll try it

Comment: yes, right... Good Luck, Mate